# Ruby or Rails method to limit query results by column

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hashtag

In my rails application, I have a Hashtag table with 4 columns:

- id
- post_id (the id of the post that the tag is associated with)
- tag (the string that is the actual hashtag)
- tagging_user_id (the user who created the hashtag)

in my index method, I want to return all Hashtags created by a given user:

```
def index
    @hashtags = Hashtag.where("tagging_user_id = ?", params[:tagging_user_id]).reverse_order
end
```

which, as expected, gives me every hashtag created by the user.

**However**, I'd really like to only get one of each hashtag to give show to the user, the individual db entries don't really matter. Is there a rails method to give me unique Hashtag entries based on the "tag" column, so I dont get multiple of the same tag?

Alternatively, should I be handling this abstraction in my application instead of my API call?

Thanks,
JA

Comment: Just do not create duplicates. Use method find_or_create when user tries to create a new tag. If there is already a tag with similar title, rails will not create, but select it from db.

Comment: @PavelTkackenko Your comment is not related to the question..

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean something like `pluck` does:

```
Hashtag.where(tagging_user_id: params[:tagging_user_id]).
        reverse_order.
        pluck('DISTINCT tag')
```

Read: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck

Comment: I don't think this has been asked.. :-) He want unique hastag entries.. Not unique tags..

Comment: He described that table like this: _tag (the string that is the actual hashtag)_ @ja. can you please charify this?

Comment: I want a list of hashtags that the use has used previously, so It doesn't matter how many times they've used it. I don't want multiple rows of the db if they have the same value for 'tag'

Comment: @ja : Okay then, I think my answer should work for you. Doesn't it?